# Evaporation of water using a vacuum pump?

Tags: thermodynamics

Is it possible to boil the water simply using vacuum pump?

Also, is there any chances of ice formation?
If yes, then how we can calculate the heat given to the water to avoid ice formation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to boil water at room temperature with a vacuum pump. It is [widely published](https://www.google.com/search?q=boiling%20water%20in%20a%20vacuum).

Boiling removes heat energy from the water which can lead to freezing if the temperature gets low enough. Again, [published many places](https://www.google.com/search?q=boiling%20water%20in%20a%20vacuum%20ice). This [youtube video](https://youtu.be/2IOyJa8NSk0?t=175) shows it well.

Avoiding ice formation during this process is a thermodynamic balance between heat input to the water from its surroundings and heat loss via low-pressure evaporation. I recommend asking this in a new question with some specific details, like pressure, temperature, container type, temperature, and your purpose and we might be able to help.